# Validar una cadena en C

Tags: c

Estoy trabajando en un programa donde te pregunte tu mes de nacimiento y si no lo escribes como "enero, febrero,marzo,etc" te vuelva a preguntar el mes de nacimiento y despues tu año. Intente hacerlo con un do while pero no me funciona. Alguna idea de como puede lograr el objetivo del programa?

```
do{

printf("Ingresa tu mes de nacimiento\n");

        scanf("%s",mes);
    }while(mes!="enero");
    if(mes!="enero"){
        printf("error");
    }else
    {


        do{

    printf("Ingresa tu año de nacimiento\n");
        scanf("%i",&year);
        }while(year>=2018 || year<=1950);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

En C no puedes comparar el contenido de cadenas con == o !=. Así solo compararías que ambas cadenas tienen la misma dirección de memoria, pero no su contenido en caracteres. Para eso tienes que usar las funciones de comparación de cadenas, como son strcmp, definidas en string.h.

Tendrías que cambiar

```
while( mes != "enero");
```

por algo como:

```
while( strcmp( mes, "enero") != 0));
```

y lo mismo para el if:
cambia

```
if( mes != "enero") {
```

por algo como:

```
if( strcmp( mes, "enero") != 0)
```

La función `strcmp` retorna 0 si las cadenas son iguales (los caracteres),

Esto en cuanto a comparación de cadenas. El bucle do-while inicial no tiene mucho sentido así como lo has escrito. Estaría dando vueltas siempre que se cumpla la condición del while y esta condición es que el mes introducido sea distinto de enero. Estará dando vueltas escribas lo que escribas hasta que introduzcas la palabra enero. Entiendo que no es lo que quieres hacer. Si quieres que solo introduzca un mes, tendrías que hacer algo como:

```
do {
.....
} while(( strcmp( mes, "enero") != 0) && (strcmp( mes, "febrero") != 0) && ...); //Una condición por cada mes
```

Saldría del bucle en cuanto introduzcas uno de los meses.

Suerte.

Answer (score 0):

para comparar cadenas puedes utilizar strcmp.

```
if (strcmp(mes, "enero") == 0)
{
    printf("el mes es enero");
}
else if(strcmp(mes, "febrero") == 0)
{
   printf("el mes es febrero");
}
.
.
.
else if (strcmp(mes, "diciembre") == 0)
{
   printf("el mes es diciembre");
}
else
{
 printf("el valor ingresado no es un mes");
}
```

para el do - while deberias utilizar un or para los valores ingresados.

```
do {
 // tus instrucciones, en este caso volver a preguntar por el mes
}
while (strcmp(mes, "enero") != 0) || strcmp(mes, "febrero") != 0 || strcmp(mes, "marzo") != 0 ) // continuar para los meses restantes
```